# Count occurrences of field values as they are displayed in order

Tags: sql, oracle

thanks in advance for the help and sorry for how the "table" looks. Here's my question...

Let's say I have a subquery with this table (imagine the **bold** as column headers) as its output -

**id** 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6

**action** o c o c c o c o o c c c

I would like my new query to output -

**id** 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6

**action** o c o c c o c o o c c c

**ct** 1 2 1 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 3

**#c** 0 1 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 2 3

**#o** 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

where **ct** stands for count. Basically, I want to count (for each **id**) the occurrences of consecutive **id** and **action** as they happen. Let me know if this makes sense, and if not, how I can clarify my question.

Note: I realize the lag/lead functions may be helpful in this situation, along with the row_number() function. Looking for as many creative solutions as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `row_number()` analytic function:

```
select id, action, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as ct
from table t;
```

For `#c` and `#o`, you want cumulative sum:

```
select id, action, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as ct,
       sum(case when action = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by id order by <some column here>) as "#c",
       sum(case when action = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by id order by <some column here>) as "#o"
from table t;
```

The one caveat is that you need a way to specify the order of the rows -- an id or date time stamp or something.  SQL result sets and tables are inherently unordered, so there is no idea that one row comes before or after another.

Comment: I do have a timestamp field which I did not include for simplicity's sake. This looks great - thanks so much for your speedy response!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you have titled this question? Couldn't find the solution I was looking for no matter what question I tried searching for.

Comment: Your title was ok.  If you ask more questions, you should learn to put the tables in a vertical format rather than a horizontal format (hint:  use four spaces at the beginning of each row).

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select id, action,
  2  row_number() over(partition by id order by rowid) ct,
  3  sum(decode(action,'c',1,0)) over(partition by id order by rowid) c#,
  4  sum(decode(action,'o',1,0)) over(partition by id order by rowid) o#
  5  from t1
  6  /

        ID A         CT         C#         O#                                   
---------- - ---------- ---------- ----------                                   
         1 o          1          0          1                                   
         1 c          2          1          1                                   
         2 o          1          0          1                                   
         3 c          1          1          0                                   
         3 c          2          2          0                                   
         3 o          3          2          1                                   
         3 c          4          3          1                                   
         4 o          1          0          1                                   
         5 o          1          0          1                                   
         6 c          1          1          0                                   
         6 c          2          2          0                                   
         6 c          3          3          0
```

P.S. Sorry Gordon, didn't see your post.